# How to do integration test for a service that depends on another service in a microservice environment?

Tags: go, testing, microservices, integration-testing

I am building a microservice app, and currently writing some tests. The function that I am testing is below where it's owned by `cart` service and tries to get all cart items and append the item details with other details of each item from `catalog` service.

```
func (s *Server) Grpc_GetCartItems(ctx context.Context, in *pb.GetCartItemsRequest) (*pb.ItemsResponse, error) {
    // Get product ids and its quantity in cart by userId
    res, err := s.Repo.GetCartItems(ctx, in.UserId)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Return empty response if there is no items in cart
    if len(res) == 0 {
        return &pb.ItemsResponse{}, nil
    }

    // Get Product ID Keys from map
    ids := GetMapKeys(res)

    // RPC call catalog server to get cart products' names
    products, err := s.CatalogClient.Grpc_GetProductsByIds(ctx, &catalogpb.GetProductsByIdsRequest{ProductIds: ids})
    if err != nil{
        return nil, err
    }

    // Return response in format product id, product name, and qty in cart
    items, err := AppendItemToResponse(products, res)
    if err != nil{
        return nil, err
    }

    return items, nil
}
```

The problem is for the test setup, I need to seed some test data to both of the `cart` and `catalog` repositories. I can do that with `cart` repo just fine, but for the `catalog` is it a common practice to just mock the dependency `s.CatalogClient.Grpc_GetProductsByIds` instead? I am still new to testing, and from what I understand you generally don't do mocking in integration tests, but I am not sure if there's a better way to tackle this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in that for an integration test you would not mock a service.

Usually, if it is a service you do not have control over, you would stub the service.

Integration tests can be run against staging or testing services (in an E2E capacity) or in a virtual environment (like compose, K8S, etc.).

I think for your requirement, I would stage it using docker-compose or something similar. If you intend to go for an E2E setup in the future, you may want to look into having a testing environment.

See: https://www.testenvironmentmanagement.com/types-of-testing-environments/

Comment: Could you kindly describe the staging process using docker-compose in this specific case? I am not too familiar with it.

Comment: It would be the same as any other, just some arbitrary environment to run against, this could be in your pipeline or some PAAS for your compose. It does not matter where the environment sits, just that it exists at the time of test.

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory "you should not be calling one microservice directly from another" comment.  While you can find a way to make testing work, you've tightly coupled the architecture.  This (testing) concern is only the first of what will become many since your `cart` service directly ties to your `catalog` service.  If you fix you [close-coupled architecture](https://www.capitalone.com/tech/software-engineering/how-to-avoid-loose-coupled-microservices/) problem, your testing problem will also be resolved.

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to the synchronous call to the `catalog` grpc server? I think in this specific case I need it to be synchronous since the client making the  REST request to the backend-for-frontend server (and in turn calling this `cart` service) is waiting for a response. I am not sure how to make asynchronous call / message based communication work if there is a client waiting for a response asap.

Comment: I think he means event driven architecture, whereby you use a message broker to queue your communications and provide redundancy.

Comment: @Ale8k Yes that's what I thought. But there is an issue (it might be obvious to you) that I just can't figure out the answer to. I just posted it as [a new question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/435753/what-is-the-common-practice-to-serve-a-rest-api-based-request-asynchronously). Answer is appreciated.